# What game is this (possibly recolored) sprite of a girl with a sword from?

Tags: game-identification

I'm developing a game and have some concerns about the originality of the artwork that a collaborator has shown me. A friend of mine tells me that this sprite looks familiar to him but he can't quite place it.

[image]

Is this a (possibly recolored or otherwise modified) sprite from an existing game?

Update: It is stolen art. The original has been found [here](http://abysswolf.deviantart.com/art/Lightning-Idle-251532357) thanks to Martin Sojka.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's pretty obviously Lightning, from Final Fantasy 13.  They've made a sprite version, so not completely the same, but not at all original.

For comparison:

[image]

Comment: A google search for "final fantasy lightning sprite" has revealed that the art is indeed stolen. Thank you for the fast response. http://www.8bitcraft.com/sprites/final-fantasy-13-lightning-standing.php

Comment: @evenex_code: You should probably link to the [original](http://abysswolf.deviantart.com/art/Lightning-Idle-251532357) instead.